# What is the difference between a p2p network and a mesh network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, p2p

As already stated in the question, I was wondering what the difference between these two network (p2p and mesh) types is. I mean, in both of them all nodes are connected without a central server, and data is transported via different users using another users as hopping station. So, is it the same if I write a p2p network program, or a program which helps me creating a mesh? Even a research in the internet didn't tell me a difference. So maybe someone can help me here?

Comment: I have already read that question, but I didn't understand everything. Is an Ad-Hoc-network always a p2p-network? Furthermore, afaik for p2p-networks it is possible to hop via users, and therefore they aren't relying on existing nodes, too. Is that correct?

Comment: http://p2pfoundation.net/Mesh_Networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the difference between a p2p network and a mesh network?**

Reference [Mesh Networks](http://p2pfoundation.net/Mesh_Networks):

> **Definition**
>
> "Mesh networks - are highly distributed networks which use special
>   routing technology. In standard routing technology as used to send and
>   receive information via the internet the 'routes' which data packets
>   take are fixed. In mesh networks the software decides 'dynamically' or
>   'ad-hoc' which route data packets take. Sometimes 'mesh networking'
>   and 'ad-hoc networking' are used as synonyms. In wireless and mobile
>   networks mesh networking has the obvious advantage that the software
>   adapts dynamically to changes in the structure or 'topology' of the
>   network. There are a number of routing protocols which support mesh
>   networking amongst which OLSR is one of the most advanced and most
>   widely used ones."

...

> **Meshworks are different from P2P Networks**
>
> As far as I understand the distinction, P2P works on the existing
>   infrastructure, which may or not be P2P itself, while meshworks create
>   a new infrastructure which is much more thoroughly distributed.
>
> From a discussion of a Technology Review article at
>   http://www.technologyreview.com/Infotech/18284/page1/
>
> "In a P2P network, the physical infrastructure still looks like a
>   tree, but the bandwidth is more efficiently employed because
>   underutilized branches can become content distributors as well as
>   receivers. A P2P network does not increase the total bandwidth
>   available, it just uses the bandwidth better.
>
> In a mesh network, users form new infrastructure by connecting
>   directly (and often through multiple alternate pathes), and the
>   network no longer looks like a tree. A mesh network increases the
>   system's total bandwidth.
>
> Both P2P and mesh networks benefit from "network effects" (i.e., the
>   more users, the better the network), and they are complementary
>   approaches. However, mesh networks have a number of benefits that P2P
>   networks do not, including increasing the resiliency of the network
>   and reducing the control that any ISP can exert over the content
>   distributed on the network and the cost of connection."

Comment: If the p2p network uses a "find new clients"-function, wouldn't that destroy the tree-image? That would add new clients, and they all can talk to each other. If one file is not avaliable at one client, they can do multi-hopping, or am I wrong?

Comment: There are two kinds of p2p structured (tree like) and unstructured (mesh like). They find files differently. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Different names. :)

Although there are several particularities with each kind of P2P network, P2P network and mesh network are effectively synonyms in a broad sense.

Comment: That means if I write e.g. an Android App which is able to create and join a p2p-network, that is a mesh network, too?

Comment: Absolutely. There's no central infrastructure, so it's a mesh.